# Reading individual statements in an Sqlite dump

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite database and I want to dump and read individual statements from the dump. The problem I am encountering is that the individual statements can span multiple lines. So, I can't just read the dump file line-by-line. Is there a way to change the default line separator for .dump/.output command?

Answer (score 0):

The `.dump` command always use a new-line as separator.

Any combination of characters (except a single `'`) is valid inside a string, and semicolons are valid inside a trigger body. To be able to read individual statements, you'd have to implement an SQL parser.

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to reinvent a new SQL parser and that's why I am trying to see if there is a way around.